# Minimax and Infinity norm

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces

I am reading a paper on Q-learning with the state space and action space denoted as $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ respectively. Under a certain policy $\pi$, the value function and Q-function is related via the following
$$
V(s)=\max_{b\in\mathcal{A}}Q(s',b).
$$
However, in the paper, they explain that
$$
-\|Q\|_{\infty}\leq \min_{s\in\mathcal{S}}V(s)\leq \max_{s\in\mathcal{S}}V(s)\leq \|Q\|_{\infty}.
$$

I don't really understand this line. Does it have to do with minimax theory? And what is the infinity norm referring to?